# Get a range of keys with redis?

Tags: redis

Something that comes up all the time with our data set at work is needing to query for a bunch of values given a range of keys. Date ranges are an obvious example.

I know you can use unix timestamps and a sorted set to query by date ranges, but it seems annoying, because I'd have to either

1. put the whole document as the value in the sorted set, or
2. just put ids in it, then ask redis for each key.

Maybe option 2 is standard? Is there a way to ask redis for multiple keys at once? Like mongodb's $in query? Or perhaps asking for a bunch of keys in a pipeline is just as fast?

Comment: option 2 is standard. there is a MGET for multiple keys.  http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Options 2, put Ids into sorted set then use mget to get values out, if your keys are hashes then you need to issue multiple hget, but the advantage is that you can pull out specific parts of the object that you actually need instead of everything. It is very fast in practice.

Comment: Interesting. I imagine you'd want to use pipeline too? It's possible I'll want to regularly pull out 100 values this way. It seems like this is possible with SORT too, right? Is it any slower?

Comment: Depending on what language/library you are using pipelining is usually built in, for example for node.js node_redis will do it for you with no extra effort. You can also use the sort trick but I am not sure if it is actually faster in any measurable way. Would love to see some benchmarks for it.

Comment: You should use pipelining, I measured the performance of it and it's roughly 5 times faster working with 10k keys, results on my blog http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/python-redis-py-pipeline

Comment: is this still the correct answer in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some bash magic helps?

```
echo 'keys YOURKEY*' | redis-cli | sed 's/^/get /' | redis-cli
```

This will output the data from all the keys which begin with YOURKEY

Comment: **Important note:** `KEYS` command is blocking and may take a long time if you have lots of data. You can take down servers/applications this way.

Comment: ^ Use SCAN instead